# Internet connection on redhat 8 in vmware

Tags: internet, vmware, connection, redhat-enterprise-linux, workstation

When I select DHCP then I can browse Internet but when I manually set IP address I can not browse on my vmware workstation. How can I configure my laptop & VMware workstation to browse internet manually. Please solve all the prosses step by step.

Answer (score 0):

To configure a static IP address, you have to configure what DHCP would otherwise do for you.

This means you need to have at least:

- correct IP address
- correct netmask
- one or more correct DNS servers
- correct gateway.

In addition to that, you need to ensure that the network interface is up and connected to the virtual switch.

There are several ways how to do that, I suggest you start [with the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/index) or by [googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=rhel+configure+static+ip), which typically [takes you just a fraction of time needed to ask a question](https://www.tecmint.com/set-static-ip-address-in-rhel-8/).